# Custom taxonomy page uses index.php

Tags: custom-taxonomy, page-template

Read a couple of tutorials (here's [one](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-dynamic-taxonomy-pages-with-wordpress/)) but I don't understand why I can't make it work. I'm trying to create a page for custom taxonomy terms. Like mysite.com/tag/term or mysite.com/category/term but for my taxonomy.

**This is what I've done so far:**

1. I registered the new taxonomy

   ```
   add_action( 'init', 'register_taxonomy_author' );

   function register_taxonomy_author() {
        register_taxonomy(  'author', 'post',   //Let WordPress know that the artist   taxonomy has posts
   array(
       'hierarchical' => false,
       'label' => 'Authors', // This tells WordPress how to label the various user interface outlets for the artist taxonomy
       'query_var' => true,
       'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'author', 'with_front' => false ))
       );
   }
   ```
2. Added a new file called taxonomy-author.php and copied+pasted the codes from category.php into it.

   ---

Now, when I try to view the taxonomy terms (Admin Panel > Posts > Authors > View) I get directed to mysite.com/author/term, which is great. But that page uses index.php instead of taxonomy-author.php. What did I miss? [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) states that index.php should be at the bottom, yet it ignores both taxonomy-author.php and my archive.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I forgot you can do this. Anyway the problem was that author was a reserved name. I have no idea why it worked for s_ha_dum though, but changing the name would be the safest option.

Comment: "*I forgot you can do this*" - It's not that you *can* do this, but rather that you *should* do this. Stack Exchange sites are not support forums, but rather Question-and-Answer sites.